# Can't install maven, system does not recognize "mvn" command line

Tags: java, maven, exist-db

I set my user and system enviorment vars as:

```
mvn PATH="D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.8.1";%PATH%
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15
J2_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin
```

and my system still can't recognize "mvn" as a valid command, can someone help please?
Already rebooted.

Comment: That is not how you set environment variables.

Comment: Note `mvn.cmd` is in bin subfolder

Comment: In your PATH variable you have to use the bin folder like `...\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin` instead. apart from that you have to configure that in your environment variables in Windows. Using the part `mvn PATH="D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.8.1";%PATH%` will not work. You have to set first `PATH` and afterwards you can call `mvn ...` ...